# In Wolfram Mathematica, who do I query the result of a Counts operation efficiently and conveniently?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

**EDIT** At the suggestion of @HighPerformanceMark, I've moved the question to mathematica.stackexchange.com: [my question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222320/in-wolfram-mathematica-who-do-i-query-the-result-of-a-counts-operation-efficien), so I attempted to close the question here. But SO doesn't allow me to do it properly, hence this up-front warning.

**Setup**

Say, I'm given a dataset, like the one below:

`titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]; titanic`

Answering with:

[image: Sample of the Titanic example data]

And I want to count the occurrences of any combination between `{ "1st", "2nd"}` and `{"female", "male"}`, using the `Counts` operator on the dataset, like:

`genderclasscounts  = titanic[All, {"class", "sex"}][Counts]`

[image: Gender Class combination counts]

**Problem statement**

This is *not* a "flat" dataset and I don't have a clue how to query in the usual way, like:

`genderclasscount[Select[ ... ], ...]`

The resulting dataset doesn't provide "column" names to be used as parameters in the `Select` nor can I refer to the number representing the count by a name.

And I've no clue how to express an `Association` as a value in a `Select`!?

Furthermore, try `genderclasscount[Print]`, this demonstrates the values presented to the operation over this dataset are just numbers!

**An unsatisfactory attempt**

Of course, I can "flatten" the `Counts` result, by doing something horrific and inefficient like:

```
temp = Dataset[(row \[Function] 
     AssociationThread[{"class", "sex", "count"} -> row]) /@ (Nest[
      Normal, genderclasscounts, 3] /. 
     Rule[{Rule["class", class_], Rule["sex", sex_]}, 
       count_] -> {class, sex, count})]
```

[image: Flattened Counts over a dataset result]

In this form it is easy to query a count result:

`First@temp[Select[#class == "1st" \[And] #sex == "female" &], "count"]`

**Question**

So, my questions are

1. How can I query the (immediate) result of the `Count` operation in a convenient and efficient fashion, like using a `Select` operation on the resulting dataset? Or, if that is not possible;
2. Is there an efficient and convenient transformation of the `Counts` result dataset possible facilitating such a query?  With "convenient" I mean, for example, that you just provide the dataset and the transformation handles the rest. So, not something like I've shown above in my unsatisfactory "solution" ;-)

Thanks for reading this far and I'm looking forward to anwsers and inspiration.

/@nanitous

Comment: You might care to move this question to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com  There is larger community of people knowledgeable about *Mathematica* over there.

Comment: Any suggestion are welcome. So, will certainly try this. Thanks @HighPerformanceMark!